# Edge loop select in linux

Tags: modeling, loop

In Linux Mint pressing the Alt+LMB moves windows. How would I select an edge loop in this situation?

Comment: you can change the shortcut preferences in the Preferences > Keymap, in the search field type "lasso", then 3D View > Lasso Select, unfold the first one and choose the shortcut. Maybe you can change the shortcut in Linux instead?

Comment: Or you can go into the linux settings and change the alt button to be the windows flag button instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try both. Sure one of them will work, or both, maybe.

Comment: moonboots suggestion got me on the right track. However, I had to go to 3D View > Loop Select where I could change it to Ctrl+LMB.

Answer (score 0):

So, open your applications "start" menu, search for 'window manager tweaks', under the accessibility tab you should see a drop down to change the button that grabs and moves windows.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Svensson and Dsharp90, it is better to change the shortcut of the window manager.  I had the same problem in Mate.